# Angular2 Dart - form validator validateEqual

Tags: validation, angular, dart

I tried to validate a password confirmation input, but I cannot find a correct built-in validator for this.

I tried :

```
<input id="passwordConfirmation" name="passwordConfirmation"    class="form-control" type="password"
                       [(ngModel)]="form.passwordConfirmation" ngControl="passwordConfirmation" #passwordConfirmation="ngForm"
                       required pattern="{{form.password}}">
```

But the `pattern="{{form.password}}"` doesn't work.

Do I have to implement a custom validator ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Valditators passed as attributes currently have to be static and can't be bound with `"{{form.password}}"`. With model driven forms this is more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm surprised attributes have to be static, but I guess it's going to change.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is going to change. (it was changed recently in TS)

Answer (score 0):

There is recently closed issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7393.

Without it, it seems like the only way to bind pattern is to implement custom validator. Something like

```
const MY_PATTERN_VALIDATOR =
const Provider(NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: MyPatternValidator, multi: true);

@Directive(
    selector:
    '[myPattern][ngControl],[myPattern][ngFormControl],[myPattern][ngModel]',
    providers: const [OK_PATTERN_VALIDATOR],
    host: {
      'pattern': 'value'
    })
class MyPatternValidator implements Validator {
  ValidatorFn _validator;
  String value;

  Map<String, dynamic> validate(AbstractControl c) {
    return _validator(c);
  }

  @Input()
  set myPattern(String value) {
    _validator = Validators.pattern(value);
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: This change is currently TS only. Dart doesn't have the new forms module yet.